# Build Freebsd from source (LFS like)

Tags: freebsd, source, linux

Do you know any project/document similar to [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/index.html) for FreeBSD?

Any pointers to build FreeBSD from scratch is appreciated. It is for learning purpose similar to LFS.

Comment: Did you even look at freebsd.org for the official documentation?

Comment: Can you please provide any link for the same. In the Freebsd handbook I could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make buildworld` is as close as the BSD world ever really got with this:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/makeworld.html

Comment: `make buildkernel` + `make buildworld` is building everything from source. Even the boot sector will get compiled from assembly source files.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/fbsd-from-scratch/